# Curl request not hitting apex rest webservice

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, curl, salesforce

I am trying to hit apex rest webservice from php using curl.I am getting the access token but my request not hitting the webservice as there are no logs generated from the salesforce side.But tested same request from postman and  its working as required.
Previously i was  getting Http error code 307.Now i am not recieving any error code.

```
    $rAuth = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://dare.net/wpsf_auth.php/'));
    $accessToken = $rAuth->access_token;
    $url = 'https://dev2193--tfdev.cs47.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/wordpress/registration';
   
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($ret_res);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
   $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

And code generated by POSTMAN:

```
POST /services/apexrest/wordpress/registration HTTP/1.1
Host: dev2193--tfdev.cs47.my.salesforce.com
Authorization: Bearer ***********************************************
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3f12eef1-700d-83ad-f1bf-ef3ad6c266f5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Salesforce server is located on a different domain: https://dev2193--tfdev.my.salesforce.com/

If you take a look at the JSON you get from https://dare.net/wpsf_auth.php, you'll see that "instance_url" attribute is pointing to a different domain.

Also, HTTP code 307 is a temporary redirect, meaning you should look at a different URL.